# Saving long text to PHP web service from iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, post, nsmutableurlrequest

I am working on a application where I need to save some long text to MySQL database using PHP web service. I have created web services but I am not able to send parameter from iPhone to PHP web service. Following is my code for web service:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$username = $_POST["username"];
$aboutme = $_POST["aboutme"];

$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die('Connection to database failed: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die ('select_db failed!');
$query = "insert into Member(username, aboutMe) values(.'".$username."', '".$aboutme."')";
echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo $result;
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I have found code to post data to web service but I am not able to add data to post request.

```
status=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&interestedIn=%@&aboutme=%@&profilePic=%@&isFBLogin=%@&useFacebookPic=%@",[@"aaaaaaaaaa" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],[@"bbbbbb" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],[@"female" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],[@"about meeeeeeeee" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],[@"profile.png" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],[@"0" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],[@"0" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    //status = @"username=pankaj1234&aboutme=Hello Baby 1234567890 0987654321";
    NSData *postData = [status dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSData *postData = [status dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/registerUser.php"]];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"success!");
```

How will I add these values to the request?

Comment: are you able to receive parameter at server side. just print the $username and $aboutme at server side to see whether the data is actually coming that way or not?

Comment: no I am not able to receive parameters at the sever side

Comment: follow what @Gilad has suggested. Because To receive this data you will need to send name-value pair at server side, as in normal GET request. But here in your iOS code you are not providing this information, so when you ask $_POST["username"] in php scipt there is no data. To quick check this use @"username=pankaj&status=onli
ne" to generate body data.

Comment: You also might want to sanitise that database input, use mysql_real_escape() before you enter that into your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are posting a www form, but you don't encode the data properly.

A form has the following syntax: `key=value&key=value` where both key/value are url encoded.

Your encoded string ('status') should be encoded as the following:

```
status=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&aboutme=%@",[username stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],[about stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

You can then use the rest of the code to convert it to NSData and post to your webservice.